# Angular ng-show date within time from or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, font-awesome

So I have a button that when clicked displays a list of data. I am adding a font awesome font in there if the JSON key value exists. But here is the problem. The key is a date. I need my ng-show to check if this date is within 30 days of todays date. My code for button is:

```
                <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 4 ? -1 : 4)"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="ppt.Dates.key == todaysDate"></i>recent denials</button>
```

The object array in JSON is:

```
"Dates": [
{
  "key": "2/25/2016",
  "value": "The last day to add or edit your March GoNavia Commuter Benefits order."
},
{
  "key": "3/31/2016",
  "value": "The last day to submit claims for your 2015 Health Care FSA."
},
{
  "key": "3/31/2016",
  "value": "The last day to submit claims for your 2015 Day Care FSA."
}
],
```

How can I achieve this correctly? Have tried with using '.length <='  type of thing, but no luck.

Thanks much.

Comment: You're going to have to find a way to compare dates as an expression in the ng-show. Here's a start, the trick is getting the formatting right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function in your controller (assuming controller as ppt):

```
this.checkDate = function (dateString) {
    var daysAgo = new Date();
    daysAgo.setDate(daysAgo.getDate() - 30);
    return (new Date(dateString) > daysAgo);
}
```

And then:

```
<button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 4 ? -1 : 4)"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="ppt.checkDate(ppt.Dates[index].key)"></i>recent denials</button>
```